# How to compile webpage Code in PHP?

Tags: php

I am a beginner in PHP language and I have bought a PHP webpage code.

[image: inside the .zip file]

[image: login]

Now I want to do changes(for example change the pictures etc) in my code and now compile the new code. I have asked many times the programmer that did my code but he does not answer me. In this webpage I am doing the connection between Raspberry pi data and web. How can I compile my code by myself?

Comment: With PHP no need to compile it's script language juste run it with webserver  or php-cli

Comment: Just change the code, the changes will show on live website instantly. You should backup the files before changing them or develop on a testing server first, in case your code comes up with errors.

Comment: PHP code is interpreted and therefore compiled every time you access a script (leaving out caching tools for now) Any resources like images/css/fonts/js are also picked up and included on the fly. So there is no need or capability to compile this or any other PHP based site

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't need compilation as it is written in PHP. PHP is interpreted, that meaning that it is read as it was written in real time.

I would check what that db.txt says, it could be a kind of "readme file".

To execute your code you just have to put it in a php web server if it is not already.

You can start see changes as soon as you edit your code.

Comment: _You can start see changes as soon as you edit your code..._ ... and run the code

Comment: inside the db.txt is the Manage user privilege, so username, Database name, Server: localhost, Database, Table and the login webpage. How can I put it in the php webserver?

Comment: Is the code live? Is it in a server? If the answer is yes, it's as I said before and as B001 added, edit and run the code (access the page)

Comment: So, when I make changes in the PHP code and refresh the webpage will it make changes?

Comment: Yes that is correct, PHP doesn't need another step of compilation.
How are you accessing the page without a server right now?

Comment: The coder sent me the http//....login.php address and the credentials too. So I login there with the username and password that he gave me. So he put the webpage in server but when I make changes in the codes that he sent me in the zip file nothing happens. Sorry that I do not understand that much about php.

Comment: Do you have any access to that server? Are you still going to use his server?

Comment: He said to me that if the webpage doesnt work I have to write him an email and he will solve it. How do I know if he gave me the access to the server?

Comment: The information that he gave me for the Server is The Localhost number, the Database name and the Table name. He also game me a name and a password(except those for webpage login) that I dont know where to login with them.

Comment: Do you have ftp credentials? Something like IP, user and password. If not, do as he said if you still want to use his server. He will certainly not be responsible for any unauthorized changes.
Do you want to host it outside that server? If the answer is yes, you should buy web hosting and that I think will be outside of the scope of stackoverflow.